# How can i select every other row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to know how i can get only every other row from a table.

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

but of course i only get the 2nd row and not 2, 4, 6, ...

Is there a solution to do that ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler version

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MOD(id,2) = 0 ORDER BY id DESC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07ea4/6)

Change 0 to 1 for odd numbers

Comment: That's awesome, simple and clean, Thank you for your help David.

Comment: Bear in mind this only works if your `id`s are contiguous. It won't work for example if you have a hole like this: 1, 2, 4, 5, 6. It *does* work if you want every *even id*, but not if you want every *alternate row*.

Answer (score 5):

There's a sneaky trick with user variables you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name, (SELECT @c := 0) t 
WHERE (@c := @c + 1) % 2 = 0
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This works because `@c` is calculated for every row (in the `WHERE` clause), and we're only selecting *even* records (2, 4, 6, ...) through the mod `%` operator.

If you want *odd* records (1, 3, 5, ...), change that `...% 2 = 0` to `...% 2 = 1`.

Comment: Wow it sounds a bit sketchy but it will do the trick, Thank you very much for your help Jeremy